# How to buy a bond? 

Tags: bonds, puerto-rico

Since this question has been a tumbleweed I wanted to update the description to see if I get any answers.

This is the information that I have:

> [PR SALES TAX FING CORP A-1 RV CAV6.30 BE/R CUSIP: 74529JMD4](http://trades.municipalbonds.com/bonds/issue/74529JMD4)

Could anyone point me on how to buy this kind of bond?

Answer (score 1):

In order to do any kind of investment transaction, such as buying stocks or bonds, you generally need an investment account.

Most large *full-service* banks have investment accounts and advisers available.  There are also often smaller investment-only companies.

Once you have an account open and funded with cash or other assets, then generally you can buy and sell what you like, within the limits of that cash.

Bonds, however, unlike stocks (also known as *equity*) are not as visible to trade as stocks on exchanges are.

Most bond transactions are conducted broker-to-broker, and bonds issued by smaller entities or with specific characteristics may be harder to find, or may command a premium to purchase due to their scarcity.

Given that you have a specific bond issue in mind, it might well be worth asking the broker you are going to deal with up front if they can access liquidity (i.e. can find you some) of the bond issue in question.  No point setting up an account and then being told that they cannot for some reason or another.

*Sometimes* in rare cases the issuing entity itself (government more likely, company less so) will sell the bonds directly to end users.  You then have a bit of paper that you hold on to, but if you want to sell it before it expires, you would usually still need a brokerage account.

Answer (score 0):

Agree with the answer above,

PLUS, to demonstrate,
I just logged onto my Etrade account (an investment/brokerage account) as suggested why the answer above.  I was able to search CUSIP# 74529JMD4

Now, forgetting about whether it would be wise to buy this particular bond, I could just press the "buy" button in Etrade and, assuming I have funds in the account, Etrade would execute it.  I could also contact someone and place the order by phone.